# What is it like trading a CS:GO skin between two accounts?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I got myself a knife in CS:GO but I have two accounts which I use both, if I were to trade my knife to my other account will I be able to use it instantly and trade it back when I'm done? Or is there some delay or limitations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that if both accounts have a steam authenticator associated with them, there should be no restrictions. It's been a while since I traded though, so I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Ok, I don't think my other account has Steam authentication. Is that the phone thing? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: That is the app on the phone where you have to confirm any trades. Accounts without authentication set up have a 14? day hold period where items are held in limbo, and the trade can be cancelled at any time.

Comment: Can't test it at the moment because I just got my knife and it has a trade lock, but thanks for the help. Hopefully it works.

Answer (score 3):

> If I were to trade my knife to my other account will I be able to use it instantly and trade it back when I'm done?

Yes, you can trade it at any time. However...

> Is there some delay or limitations?

If both accounts have an authenticator for at least seven days, and do not have any bans, then **no**.

If not, then **yes** as regardless of whether you own both accounts in a trade, all trades are considered as a "business" trade and thus is subject to standard trade restrictions:

- If you have recently logged in to your account on a new machine, it will be unable to trade from that machine for 7 days. (Workaround: Complete the trade on a computer that is already established; more than 7 days since first login).
- If you do not have a Steam authenticator attached to either accounts, it is subject to 15 days in escrow.
- If one account does not have an authenticator, there is a 7 day escrow, unless... (See below)
- If both accounts have been friends for at least a year, but one does not have an authenticator, there is a 3 day escrow.
- If you do have a Steam authenticator attached on both accounts for more than 7 days, trades will go ahead instantly as soon as they're approved from the authenticator.
- If either accounts have a VAC or Trade Ban, they will be unable to trade.

**Note:** Escrow times start from the moment all sides requiring an authenticator action are completed. (You know; go to Confirmations > [...] > Accept?)

**Reminder:** You can have MULTIPLE accounts use one singular authenticator.

---

[This support page provides some information about Steam trading restrictions.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-edfm-2932#vac), though it's missing quite a few of the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If the accounts don't have a trade ban or cooldown and (if you have steam mobile authenticater) you can confirm that trade. You should have no problem!

Answer (score 0):

There will be a delay unless you have Steam mobile authenticator on your other account. Sending your knife to your other account should be no problem, because your other account does not require Steam mobile authenticator to accept a trade where it's not losing any items. The only problem is if you want to send your knife back, you might have to wait two weeks (according to my friends who don't have Steam mobile authenticator and prime).

Comment: Prime doesn't have anything in common with the steam mobile authenticator

Answer (score 0):

Set up the steam mobile authenticator for both accounts, then you can trade immediately between both of them.
 If you don't have the mobile authenticator activated on the account which trades an item away, you will have a delay of 15 days!

**Note:**

- If you recently activated the mobile authenticator, you'll still have the delay for 7 days
- You can use the same telephone number and mobile phone for multiple accounts to set up the authenticator
- If you use the same telephone number on multiple accounts and one of your account is VAC banned **ALL** linked accounts get the VAC ban

Comment: Don't forget the 3 day to 24 hour delay if you've been friends for at least a year*.

Comment: @aytimothy Do you have a reference for this? Since when does this apply? Never encountered it.

Comment: http://store.steampowered.com/news/19618/ @Artery

Comment: @aytimothy Ah, thanks. Didn't know this, yet!